# I can't print array elements (kotlin.Unit)

Tags: android, arrays, intellij-idea, kotlin

I added all codes. I want to write all of the elements of the array but I can only see " kotlin.Unit " on the screen. For example, if I ad three 'ozet' to 'bilgiler' I see three "kotlin.Unit". Is that related to arrays type? (I deleted 'Menu' function while sending)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30e46.png)

```
    package OOP

class Ogrenci constructor(var isim:String,var numara:Int)
{
fun bilgileriGoster ()
{

    println("Öğrencinin Adı: $isim"+" "+ "($numara)")

    print("İlk sınav notunu girin: ")
    var not1 = readLine()!!.toInt()

    print("İkinci sınav notunu girin: ")
    var not2 = readLine()!!.toInt()

    var ortalama:Float = (not1+not2).toFloat()/2
    println("$isim adlı öğrencinin ortalaması:"+ortalama )
}
    fun ozet()
    {
        var ozet = "$isim,$numara"
    }
}
    fun main()
{
    var bilgiler = arrayListOf<Any>(0)

 var Seçim = Menu()
while (true){
    if (Seçim==1) {
        println("Öğrenci Adını Giriniz:")
        var ad: String = readLine().toString()
        println("Öğrenci Numarasını Giriniz:")
        var numara: Int = readLine()!!.toInt()

        var ogr1: Ogrenci = Ogrenci(ad, numara)
        ogr1.bilgileriGoster()
        println()

        var ozet = ogr1.ozet()
        bilgiler.add(bilgiler.size,ozet)

        println("1-Devam")
        println("2-Çıkış")
        print("Seçim:")
        var karar = readLine()!!.toInt()

        if (karar==2)
        {
            for (index in bilgiler)
        {
            print(index)
        }
            break
        }

    }
    }
```

}

Comment: It's hard to help you without more context. One way to sort this out is to add some types, especially on `ogr1`, `ozet` and `bilgiler`. You'll probably realize the problem by yourself if you do this.

Comment: What you're writing there doesn't make any sense. Why did you put a `break` in the `if` statement? If you meant to put `break` into the `for` loop, that means that the `for` loop will break after the first iteration. In case you still have the error after removing the `break`, please post a minimal example reproducing your problem

Comment: My guess is that `ogr1.ozet()` returns unit and therefore we would need to see this function

Comment: @Fred Good catch! I assume `bilgiler` is some sort of List, but without knowing the exact type (probably `List<Unit>` or `List<Any>`) it's hard to tell

Comment: @Fred I added all of the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, the function `ozet()` returns `Unit` since it's declared like:

```
fun ozet() {
    var ozet = "$isim,$numara"
}
```

When the return type is omitted, kotlin knows it's `Unit`, so it is the same as:

```
fun ozet(): Unit {
    var ozet = "$isim,$numara"
}
```

For this reason, every time you execute it and put the result in the array you get back a `Unit` object and that's why you see `Unit`.

It's hard to say what exactly should be in the array, but I guess it's easy to realise it needs to be something returned from `ozet`.

If you want to put the contents of the variable you could simply change it to:

```
fun ozet() = "$isim,$numara"
```

This is a shorthand for:

```
fun ozet(): String {
    return "$isim,$numara"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also , How can I add 'var ortalama' to 'fun ozet():String' ?